# Display a multidimensional array as a table

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, display

As part of the development of a bot Discord, I need to display a multidimensional array, including the players' nicknames and their scores as a table with title that can be easily read by the players.
All my code is functional, I just hang on the display.

Currently, my javascript is displayed like this

```
Leriana,48
Mulhog,43
Nessyloch,29
Pokegaia,25
Holyblood,8
```

thanks to

```
var sum = {},result;
for (var i=0,c;c=score[i];++i) {
    if ( undefined === sum[c[0]] ) {        
    sum[c[0]] = c;
    }
    else {
        sum[c[0]][1] += c[1];
    }
}
result = Object.keys(sum).map(function(val) { return sum[val]});

result.sort(sortFunction);

function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[1] > b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
console.log(result);
message.channel.send(result.join("\n"));
```

I would like my array to display like this

```
Héros       Score
Leriana     48
Mulhog      43
Nessyloch   29
Pokegaia    25
Holyblood   8
```

I thank you in advance for your advice!